# How to read latest email in Gmail using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

my test scenario is if I perform some action using API, then I am receiving an email.

I have used Mail Reader Sampler to read an email. *I can successfully read the email. But the problem is it reads the oldest email*. I want to read the latest email.

**How can I read the latest email?**

I've attached the screenshot of my configuration.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the single latest message and avoid receiving all of them you will have to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and do this in [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/), example code:

```
props.setProperty('mail.transport.protocol', 'imaps')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.host', 'imap.gmail.com')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.port', '995')
props.setProperty('mail.imap.ssl.enable', 'true');

def session = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
store = session.getStore('imaps')
store.connect('imap.gmail.com', 'your-username@gmail.com', 'your-password')
inbox = store.getFolder('INBOX')
inbox.open(javax.mail.Folder.READ_ONLY)
def message = inbox.getMessage(inbox.total)
return message.getContent()
```

More information:

- [JavaMail API](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javamail.html)
- [Using Groovy to read mails from GMail.](https://gist.github.com/jresendiz27/a205a27d0704a60b18c3)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi Dimitri T, thank you for your reply. I hope your answer will work. But I have tried another approach as I needed a solution for urgent.

I use a Gmail filter and filter the message from the sender to another folder. Then I read the email from that folder using Mail Reader Sampler then I delete that email from that folder. In this way, I will always have only one email in that folder at a time

Thank you anyway for your approach. I will try next time, I am sure your answer will works.